# When I tried to create a composite primary key in a table an error is occurring?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE WorkOrder
    ADD CONSTRAINT Wo_system PRIMARY KEY (WorkOrderNumber,AssetCode)
```

When i tried to execute the query above the following error is occurring :

```
Msg 1779, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Table 'WorkOrder' already has a primary key defined on it.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

I had deleted the primary key `WorkOrderNumber` but its still creating the same error.

Can some one give me a solution for this?

Comment: `sp_helpindex WorkOrder`; what do you get?

Comment: this is wat i am getting : 1 pk_wrkord clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY WorkOrderNumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE WorkOrder
    DROP CONSTRAINT pk_wrkord 
GO
ALTER TABLE WorkOrder
      ADD CONSTRAINT Wo_system PRIMARY KEY (WorkOrderNumber,AssetCode)
GO
```

Comment: the error i got when i executed the query :                                           Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'WorkOrder'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not drop the key:

Try

```
exec sp_pkeys 'workorder'
```

Comment: its showing like : 1   WorkOrderSystem  dbo  WorkOrder  WorkOrderNumber  1  pk_wrkord

Comment: The table still has a primary key. A table can only have one primary key,

Comment: yup i deleted that primary key WorkOrderNumber now its working